# Which firebase database should I use?

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am making an account system with firebase.

I have the auth part ready.

I also want to store data for every user.

Which database should I use? Firebase Firestore or the real-time database?

Thank you!

Comment: Technology recommendations are off-topic, because they are highly subjective. Luckily the Firebase documentation contains this handy database recommender to guide you: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using Firebase Firestore for storing user's data. 
You could use Firebase Firestore instead of Real Time Database. As the name suggests, the Real Time database is useful for realtime data sharing. Eg: Sharing Score of one participants to another participants realtime.

Cloud Firestore support indexed queries with compound sorting and filtering. Unlike Realtime Database, Cloud Firestore allows chaining the filters and combining filter and sort on a property in a single query 
Realtime Database supports deep queries with limited sorting and filtering functionality. In a single query, you can either sort or filter, not both, on a property


While the Realtime Database is just a giant JSON tree, Cloud Firestore is a little more structured


You can expect to find new query types, more robust security rules, and improved performance with some other advanced features planned for Cloud Firestore

*You can set up listeners in Cloud Firestore to stream in changes in real-time*

Comment: I also saw that it is cheaper if you scale up(firestore).

Comment: When you use Firestore, you are charged for the following:

The number of reads, writes, and deletes that you perform.
The amount of storage that your database uses, including overhead for metadata and indexes.
The amount of network bandwidth that you use

Comment: Welcome! if you found the answer useful, please mark it as the best answer so that other's would also find it easily

Comment: What about storage? Which one is better?

Comment: Yes I will mark it! It is very useful!

Comment: For Storage also Firestore is better